# Propeller Rotation

Tags: animation

I am making an animation involving planes. Of course, planes need propellers. I thought this would be simple to do. All I would have to do was rotate and keyframe. This worked for the first few scenes, but in the later scenes it stopped working. In the later scenes, I would keyframe the propeller idly at the start of the shot, then I would go to the end of the shot and rotate it around 30,000 degrees. Both keyframes look good when I went to their exact frame, but in between the two frames the propeller just seemingly rotates randomly. Here are the pictures to show what is going on.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Does someone, Anyone, have an answer to my predicament?

Comment: Please consider rotating the propeller first on some world axis. Typical.  Then parent  the propeller to the plane body (wing nose et cetera).  Discuss what is the parent of the propeller in your question above please.  Show it by expanding your outliner. Or simply delete your current parenting, get the rotation of your propeller correct on some major axis .. in the set [X, Y, Z] .. . Inspect front and side.  Next parent again for a second cleaner attempt.  This is a small problem.  The parent plane should originally be aligned to a major axis world [X, Y, Z]

Comment: There should be no fine tuning for different frames.  That would typically be a sign of defect.  You may also rename object from the confusing names of Cube Blah N .. to improved names of propeller and plane and wings ....

Comment: One possibility is that you're using quaternion rotation rather than Euler rotation. Quaternions don't work well for rotations more than 360 degrees (outside of -180 to 180). In the `n`-side panel in the 3D viewport, ensure the dropdown below Rotation is set to `XYZ Euler`.

Comment: Hi @TheTrueJard and @Atomicbezierslinger! Thanks! I unparented the propeller and rotated it on the global axis. Then I re-parented it and that really worked. Thanks a lot again, you're life savers!